# Change url in local IIS to avoid port number

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to change port number in URL for page name.
Now in IIS configuration default value is :

```
http://localhost:52576/
```

I'd like to change this for :

```
 http://localhost/websiteName/
```

I am using visual studio 2013 and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Do you mean the configuration in IIS, or the configuration in the "Web" tab of the project properties? That looks like you're using "IIS Express" rather than "Local IIS"?

Comment: Hi. I found the solution for that. I have mean configuration in IIS manager. I will send solution later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not running Visual Studio as Administrator so it didn't have access to modify IIS, you'll need to do this manually.

I assume that you still have the "Default" or "Local" website in the "Sites" list within IIS.

If so, you can right-click on that and select "Add Application", select a reasonable Alias and set the "Physical path" to point to the root of your project (i.e. where the web.config and /bin/ folders are located).

[image: Add Application dialog]